# Windows Command Prompt raster fonts display at wrong resolution

Tags: windows-10, fonts, cmd.exe

I just got a new laptop (Lenovo ideapad FLEX 4-1480) with Windows 10 Home, and I have noticed a strange behavior with the Command Prompt when using Raster Fonts.  If I choose Raster Fonts and set the Size to `8 x 12`, things look as expected:
[image: 8x12]

However, when I set the Size to `8 x 8`, the Command Prompt gets much larger:
[image: 8x8]

This is pretty clearly not `8 x 8`, at least not in screen pixels.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `8 x 8` screenshot looks like the `16 x 8` (which is just below `8 x 8`).  Double check your setting.

To repair corrupted system files, run the following in an administrative command prompt: `sfc /scannow`.  Hopefully, the raster fonts are considered a system file.

As a workaround, consider using a non-raster font.  I personally prefer them anyway.

Comment: You're onto something.  I did have it set to `8 x 8`... but when I set it to `16 x 8`, it looks the same.  The fonts must have become corrupted somehow.

Comment: Try `sfc` or use non-raster fonts.  See edited answer for details